# Can I use requests.py for the Twitch API?

Tags: python, websocket, python-requests, twitch, twitch-api

I am wondering which one of these are best for python programming with the Twitch API. I know fairly well how to use requests.py when it comes to getting information from an API but I am not sure if that is the best way. On the Twitch's website they use websockets as an example and it is not even in python but in c#. What should I use?

Comment: for most APIs you can use `requests` and probably most python modules use `requests` to work with `APIs` . In documentation for some APIs you can even find examples with Python `requests`. Or you can find examples for `curl` which you can convert to `requests` on https://curl.trillworks.com/#python . Or you can find examples for `Postman` which has function to convert to different languages and there is also Python. So first you could search in API documentation if they have examples in Python, Url, Postman, Or you could search module in Python for Twitch.

Comment: I found some module for twitch and in [source code](https://github.com/PetterKraabol/Twitch-Python/blob/master/twitch/api.py) I see `requests` - so you can use it to learn something.

Comment: Yes, you can use requests.py for the Twitch API.